# I don't understand why this regex always returns false?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Ok here is is the regex:

```
Match CMD = Regex.Match(CommandString, @"\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (CMD.Success){
   return true;
}
return false;
```

the following patterns should return true:

```
(ID;Integer;12;YES;YES;YES;0)

(weak;String;5;NO;YES;YES;super)

(fabris345;decimal;23;YES;YES;YES;0)

(expr12nd;String;455;NO;YES;NO;super1000)
```

but they always return false. Why?

Comment: `a-zA-z` - weIrD RanGE.

Comment: Side note: you only need `[a-z0-9]` if you've set `IgnoreCase`

Comment: @Mat ok I fixed that but still returns false

Comment: (`[A-z]` actually includes non-alphabet characters such as `[` and `^` and `_`, so it will make it match *more*, but not less. Thus, while it should be fixed, it's likely irrelevant.)

Comment: @user2864740 or I didn't know But i still get false after I made the changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...(d{1,3})... should be (\d{1,3})

Comment: This is definitely *a* problem.